# IE9 Issue: Dynamically created (through innerHTML) option buttons and check boxes are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am working on a project that requires me to be able to grab html from a page and insert it into the main webpage.  It works totally in Chrome and Firefox, but it fails in IE 9.  Here is a cut out of the code I use.

> ```
>    if (!element.data('cache')) {
>
>        $('#contentHolder').html('<img src="ajax_preloader.gif" width="64" height="64" class="preloader" />');
>
>       $.get(element.data('page'), function (msg) {
>          $('#contentHolder').html(msg);
>
>          /* After page was received, add it to the cache for the current hyperlink: */
>             element.data('cache', msg);
>             setTimeout("checkonbox()", 100);
>         });
>     }
>     else {
>          $('#contentHolder').html(element.data('cache'));
>         setTimeout("checkonbox()", 100);
>     }
> ```

The HTML being injected is

```
<table style="width:400px; height: 388px; text-align: left;" align="left">
<tr>
<td><input id="Checkbox0" type="checkbox"  onclick="changebuttons();" checked="true">  
Exclusive.</input></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Plus some more option buttons.

Everything appears perfectly, but I can't click on the check box or option buttons.

Comment: What does your changebuttons() function do? This appears to be the most likely cause of the problem. Another thing to check is the jquery version - there have been some bugs with IE9 and older versions of jquery.

Comment: Side Note -  you don't need to end `changebuttons()` with a `;`, as you're not doing anything after the cod. just a tip, nothing serious.

Comment: I am using jquery 1.7.2.  I have also just found that the onclick event is working; the checkbox just doesn't change.  I have included the following to the top of my changebuttons function `if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
                document.getElementById('Checkbox0').checked = 1 - document.getElementById('Checkbox0').checked;
            }` and it works perfectly.

Comment: What does your IE Debugger say? Any errors? Can you put console.info statements in your code to trace what it's doing?  Not bad for a first question.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the complete code in your question. But I am assuming that you not put the code inside initializer:

```
    $(function () {
      // your jQuery code here.
    });
```

This will help the browser to initialize the events associated with its elements. Try this and check if there any change happens.

Also try to eliminate if there any error on javascript. Try to debug with available browser. The best javascript debugger I ever encountered is **FireBug**, which is a firefox addon.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen an input tag written like that. I haven't had my morning coffee yet, but I'm fairly certain that it should be self-closing, in which case I wouldn't be at all surprised to see IE barfing on what you've got there.

I guess the idea was to make the "Exclusive." label clickable, in which case you want a label tag around your input, something like this:

```
<label for="Checkbox0"><input id="Checkbox0" type="checkbox"  onclick="changebuttons();" checked="true" />Exclusive.</label>
```

Give that a whirl.

Comment: alternatively it is possible specify `for` attribute in the label tag, so there would be no need to enclose input into label

Comment: Yes of course! The for is redundant in that code. Fail... Knew I should have had that caffeine.

Answer (score 0):

anything dynamically added to the dom will have to have actions bound to it after it is loaded into the page. Just dropping the code in via AJAX will not make it run.

try doing this in your function:

```
$.get(element.data('page'), function (msg) {
         $('#contentHolder').html(msg);

         //this will bind your input field  via javascript
         $('input#Checkbox0').click(changebuttons);

         /* After page was received, add it to the cache for the current hyperlink: */
            element.data('cache', msg);
            setTimeout("checkonbox()", 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
element
```

with

```
$(element)
```

it will work.